# Setting up C and C++ code base project for sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am trying to setup Sonarqube for c and C++ based project and the clear case  tool is being used as version control tool.Can i get the step by step process to set up Sonarqube and set project,compile  c and c++ code and  analyze?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution (and free for open source) is to start by using SonarCloud, it has a step by step guide for C and C++ project:
https://about.sonarcloud.io/get-started/

Then, if you want to have an on premise sonarqube server, you can install the C/C++ plugin by following this documentation:
[SonarCFamily for C/C++](https://docs.sonarqube.org/x/_QR6)

Comment: I have installed Sonarqube, and now trying to install c and c++ plugin for same.But i couldn't see any option for same .

Comment: i am trying to use scanner for code analysis ,it's passing but no code is being analysed and i am getting some info warning like :                                                        INFO: Load active rules
INFO: Load active rules (done) | time=469ms
WARN: SCM provider autodetection failed. No SCM provider claims to support this project. Please use sonar.scm.provider to define SCM of your project.
INFO: Publish mode
INFO: -------------  Scan BL_RNC_RIF38240H4221
INFO: Load server rules